# Using ArcMap to Query and Display Data?

Tags: arcmap, attribute-table, definition-query

I have a large amount of data in Excel spreadsheets.

I have been converting that data into Attribute tables to use in ArcMap.

The data includes:

- names of locations
- geo-location
- descriptions of each location

**I need to** find an easy way that users, with only basic knowledge of ArcMap, can query the information in the tables and plot only the locations that meet the query parameters on the map, excluding the remaining data.

What would be a good way of going about this, without having to write a script?

Comment: You're asking the impossible here -- Flexible, dynamic, customizable, easy to use, and *without scripting*?

Comment: If you data is stored in tables only, then you probably have to [Add XY Data](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/adding-x-y-coordinate-data-as-a-layer.htm) first, in order to view the geography described in your tables.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are describing is the use case for [definition queries](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/displaying-a-subset-of-features-in-a-layer.htm):

> When you specify a dataset that you want to draw as a map layer, you
>   often only want to draw some of the features in the dataset. In these
>   situations, you can define a query expression to select a subset of
>   features for the layer display. This is referred to as a definition
>   query.